# modify wordpress wp_nav_menu url

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, menu

How could I change the code generated by wp_nav_menu?

Right now it generates:

```
<ul class="rounded ">
<li class="arrow"><a href="http://diner.mobileversion.co/menus/">Menus</a></li>
</ul>
```

I'd like it to look like this:

```
<ul class="rounded ">
<li class="arrow"><a href="/#menus/">Menus</a></li>
</ul>
```

i found this link, but could not get it working properly.

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-do-i-modify-wp_nav_menu-link-hrefs?replies=2

Answer (score 0):

The link from support forum doesn't talk about the version number of the wordpress that he is using. I am currently on 3.2.1, it is having the menu options under Appearance section. You can check out this [awesome post on menus](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2010/06/01/goodbye-headaches-hello-menus). It gives you an option of modifying the href as well.

I hope you are on version > 3. If not possible to update then it has to be done using wp functions.